# sprintf() and -INF return (positive) INF

Tags: php, printf

```
sprintf('%E', -INF);
```

returns `INF` (infinity without negative sign)

Is this a bug or desired behaviour?

Comment: `echo sprintf('-%E', INF);`

Comment: My guess is that, though the actual type of `INF` is `float`, the *value* is `INF` also, so when you pass it to `sprintf()`, it somewhere along the way interprets it as a string, and a negative string makes no sense, so it just returns `INF`. See [these examples](https://3v4l.org/lsP2J). I think it's definitely unexpected behavior. Will continue looking into it.